# How to call a function with json parameter in Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, psycopg2, jsonb

I have to pass a json object to a function but it's not working:

```py
import psycopg2
cur.execute(" SELECT mrp_sp_insert_jobdef( %s )",(json(_jobdef),) )

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Alternatively:

```py
cur.execute(" SELECT mrp_sp_insert_jobdef( % )",(json.dumps(_jobdef),) )

ValueError: unsupported format character ' ' (0x20) at index 31
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the wrapper [`psycopg2.extras.Json(adapted, dumps=None)`](http://psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.Json), example:

```py
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import Json

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=postgres password=password")
cur = conn.cursor()

_jobdef = {'id': 1, 'name': 'product', 'amount': 230}
cur.execute("SELECT mrp_sp_insert_jobdef( %s )", (Json(_jobdef),) )
```